# Convert a hexadecimal varbinary to its string representation?

Tags: sql-server, binary, hex, type-conversion, user-defined-functions

I have some base-64 encoded strings in SQL Server database, for example:

```
DECLARE @x VARBINARY(64);
SET @x = 0x4b78374c6a3733514f723444444d35793665362f6c513d3d
```

When it's CAST or CONVERTED to a VARCHAR, I get:

```
+Ë½Ð:¾Îréî¿•
```

I'm looking for SQL Server to return a varchar with the hexadecimal representation of the varbinary as a varchar, e.g.:

```
4b78374c6a3733514f723444444d35793665362f6c513d3d
```

Is there a build in CAST/CONVERT/function that does this, or does it have to be added as a User Defined Function? And what would the UDF be?

Bonus points if I can select whether I want capital A-F or lower case a-f in the conversion process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL2005 I would use `xsd:hexBinary` [data type](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_hexBinary.html):

```
DECLARE @x VARBINARY(64);
SET @x = 0x4b78374c6a3733514f723444444d35793665362f6c513d3d

SELECT '0x'+CONVERT(XML, '').value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@x") )', 'VARCHAR(MAX)');
SELECT '0x'+LOWER(CONVERT(XML, '').value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@x") )', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'));
```

For SQL2008+ I would use CONVERT (see [section Binary styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @x, 1)
```

References:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx

Comment: Your example uses both `hexBinary` and `CONVERT`; could you clarify which is SQL2005 and which is SQL2008+?

Comment: @Ehryk: See the last example from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx

Comment: Could you add that to your answer?

Comment: @Ehryk: Example added.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @x VARBINARY(64);
SET @x = 0x4b78374c6a3733514f723444444d35793665362f6c513d3d;

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), @x),
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), @x, 1), 3, 64);
       ----- style number is important ---^
```

Results:

```
Kx7Lj73QOr4DDM5y6e6/lQ==    4B78374C6A3733514F723444444D35793665362F6C513D3D
```

If you want lower case, just wrap the whole `SUBSTRING` operation in `LOWER()`.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/470f5/5)

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solution, `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @x, 1)`, returns "0x4B78374C...", but the question clearly wanted the result to be "4b78374c...".

By modifying the "style" parameter to `CONVERT()` and adding `LOWER()`, we get exactly what the questioner was looking for, without using `SUBSTRING()` or `RIGHT()`:

```sql
SELECT LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @x, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2008+

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @x, 1)
```