# Convert varbinary value to string to get the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert the `VarBinary` value to a `String` value and I want to get the same value as `VarBinary`. Please see the below:

```
DECLARE @RFID INT
SET @RFID = 1292202724
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @RFID) AS 'VARBINARY_VALUE'
SELECT CAST((CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @RFID)) AS NVARCHAR) AS 'STRING_VALUE' --Using Cast
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15),(CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @RFID))) AS 'STRING_VALUE' --Using Convert
```

Below is the result:

[image: Select Result]

What I want is the string value should get the same value **"0x4D0572E4"** as `VarBinary` value. But as you can see, I cannot convert to string.
If you have the solution, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a hexadecimal varbinary to its string representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968728/how-do-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-varbinary-to-its-string-representation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for `convert` you find that for binary data there is a style option of 0, 1, 2. Style option 1 gives the value in hex format.

```
DECLARE @RFID INT = 1292202724;

SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @RFID) AS 'VARBINARY_VALUE';

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @RFID), 1 /* style 1 */) AS 'STRING_VALUE'; --Using Convert
```